# Meteor Force JS script re-run

Tags: javascript, meteor

It's been a while since I'm working on a site for my WebTV with meteor, and Iron Router.
on it there is a Twitch player and my last youtube video.
I have a little problem with the router. when the user changes pages the router unload the template and the script, but once returns to the page for example "/ stream" the script that displays the player Twitch does not recharge. So the player is not displayed. The only way is to reload the complete site (F5)

I wonder if Iron Router does not have a force reload system. but after a lot of research, I did not find anything.
any idea?

Comment: Please show your template html and js for `/stream`. Do you have an `onRendered` handler for example?

Comment: Howdy! Of course you can.
i post it on pastbin cant format here (sorry i dont really know this website ^^ )
[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/wDh0ZgUB)

it's only a part but only what is important!

Comment: You're embedding twitch via a `<script>` tag. That's generally going to fail or cause problems. Try finding an Atmosphere or npm package for twitch and working with that api.

Comment: Also it's better practice to put your code straight into your question. Use the curly brace symbol in the editor.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser! i guess i shound ask on Twitch dev forums for this kind of atmosphere or NPM package.